# Cannot create a Table in Microsoft Azure Databricks based on a Microsoft Azure SQL Database Table

Tags: jdbc, azure-sql-database, databricks

I want to connect to a Microsoft Azure SQL Server and a Microsoft Azure SQL Database from my Microsoft Azure Databricks Notebook and do a SELECT and INSERT.

Lets assume i have a Microsoft SQL Server named `dev-sql-srv` reachable hostname is `dev-sql-srv.database.windows.net`.

Then i have a SQL database named `dev-sql-srv-db1`. The table is called `CUSTOMER` for example.

I have found this in the original Azure Databricks documentation at https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#spark-sql-example.

When i do

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE CustomerT1
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:sqlserver://dev-sql-srv.database.windows.net:1433",
  table "dev-sql-srv-db1.CUSTOMER",
  user "myAdmin",
  password "myPassword"
)
```

When i execute this in my notebook i am receiving the following error:

> Error in SQL statement: IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed:
>   Option 'dbtable' is required.
>   com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Option
>   'dbtable' is required.    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:81)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3320)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:124)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3319)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:194)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:639)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:707)     at
>   com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:87)

What is wrong with this example? My parameters all definitely all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the databasename to the JDBC Url:

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE CustomerT1
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:sqlserver://dev-sql-srv.database.windows.net:1433;database=dev-sql-srv-db1",
  dbtable "dbo.CUSTOMER",
  user "myAdmin",
  password "myPassword"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace "table" with "dbtable". For example,

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc 
OPTIONS ( url "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx.databse.windows.net;
DabaseName=yyyydb01;
user=someuser;
password=secret", 
dbtable "SalesLT.Product"
)
```

Comment: I have implented it as in your answer. I tried for dbtable `dbo.customer` and also `customer` but in both cases i get the following error: `com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Customer'.`

Comment: And i can guaranteee that the database name and table name is 100% correct and that the table exist and also the user has access rights (i have already tried through SSMS and Azure SQL Database Query (Preview)

Comment: Did you created firewall rules to allow access to Azure SQL Database?

Comment: At the Azure SQL DB -> Overview -> Firewalls and virtual network -> Show firewall settings -> `Allow access to Azure services` -> Set to `ON` -- Is this what you meant? Also the same setting on the database level.

Comment: But you are connecting also from outside Azure, add a rule from any public IP address outside Azure

Comment: Why am i outside Azure? I am working in Azure Databricks. And from my understanding this is also Azure. And additionally this wouldnt be that secure to add ANY public IP address.

Comment: When I said any public IP address, I meant any specific public IP you were using.

Comment: I am not using any public address cause i am trying to connect from a Databricks Notebook which runs on a Spark Cluster. And i have no idea which IPs are used cause this is an Azure Service.